# HackerRank Python print STDOUT doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, printing, stdout

I am very new to Python so am trying out the ['Counting Valleys'](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem) question on HackerRank. 
I have written my solution in PyCharm and it works fine/gives the correct answer to the expected output of the solution.

- I have tried to search on this site but nothing concrete seems to have come up for this, so I must have missed out something obvious.

The problem is that when I port the code across to HackerRank, it just says 'Wrong Answer'.

I would like to understand what the issue is by using 'print' or anything else to get feedback.

Below I have added 'print' lines to different places to show areas I have tried too.

This is the second solution that I have run into this problem, any advice/suggestions would be appreciated as its super annoying and frustrating to continue working with, any help appreciated.

```
# !/bin/python

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import logging


# Complete the countingValleys function below.
def countingValleys(n, s):
    print('Please print')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

        n = int(raw_input())
        s = raw_input()

        sea_level = 0
        valleys = 0
        last_step = ''
        in_same_valley = False
        print('Ok maybe here?')
        for step in s:
            if step == 'D':
                if last_step == 'D' and sea_level <= 0:
                    if not in_same_valley:
                        valleys += 1
                        in_same_valley = True
                sea_level -= 1
            else:
                sea_level += 1
                in_same_valley = False
            last_step = step

        print('Ok perhaps here?')
        fptr.write(str('valleys') + '\n')
        fptr.close()
    print('Ok try here?')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have indentation wrong. Try something like:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the countingValleys function below.
def countingValleys(n, s):
    print('hi')

# The below line should not be inside the function countingValleys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    ....
```

and it should work. you will see the output in the `Debug output` box at the bottom

Comment: @CristiFati - thank you, yes that sorted it in part (big part). It still wouldn't output anything, until I modified the valleys variable to '1' (pass a test case). Once at least one test case passed, then it shows STDOUT. If no test cases pass then you do not get  to see STDOUT... which is a bit strange

Answer (score 1):

## counting valley Challenge

This is how I solved my counting Valley Challenge

```
def countingValleys(n, s):
    ls = list(s)
    seeLevel = 0
    valley = 0
    for i in ls:
        if i == 'U':
            seeLevel += 1
        else:
            if seeLevel == 0:
               valley +=1
            seeLevel-= 1
    return valley
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(raw_input())
    s = raw_input()
```